# Setting search box text inside map

Tags: leaflet, search-window

I want to know how I can show that write on my search box and appear in a rectangle inside map (sync up two elements, search box and the Text area).

Like this:

[link] 
(https://design.ateljekartan.com/?lat=40.4167754&lng=-3.7037902&zoom=15&text=Madrid&orientation=landscape&styleName=fullscreen-adriatic)

Comment: Write up with demo using JQuery autocomplete, div at the top instead of a side div. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main key here is to observe changes in your input box and then set new value on another element, i.e.:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  console.log('changed');
  var newVal = $('input').val();
  $('#divOnMap').val(newVal);
});
```

Here is a working example on Leaflet and jQuery, with a container created as an extension on map.

https://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/wXdZjL

Comment: How I can get "Id" of my Mapbox style. In Codepen (link) you write "container.id", Where I can get this Id? Is it possible edit my own maps and create this Id? I have some problems with 'changed' in console.

Comment: In this line I created the element id name: `container.id = "divOnMap";` so that I could access it later with jQuery `$('#divOnMap')`. You can name it whatever you want. Feel free to play around with the codepen and change with your values

Comment: Unexpected token ILLEGAL, result